# Can anyone explain exactly what is the difference of words below in 'Hyperledger Fabric' context?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Can anyone explain exactly what is the difference of words below in Fabric context? Did some research but confused with the answers.

- Organization
- Party
- Member
- Participant
- Entity
- Identity

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Not the correct place to ask this question. Check out the [Hyperledger Fabric Docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/blockchain.html), Also check out their [RocketChat](https://chat.hyperledger.org/)